# TextBox.Text is null when the user enters data into it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to recover what users enter into textbox.

I create accessors to make my textboxes public because I've got problems of accessibility before.

Here's my full aspx.cs for the connexion :

```
public partial class ConnexionSaisieHeures : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    /*Accesseurs*/

    public string NomUtilisateur
    {
        get
        {
            return txtNomUtilisateur.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            txtNomUtilisateur.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public string MotDePasse
    {
        get
        {
            return txtMotDePasse.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            txtMotDePasse.Text = value;
        }
    }

    /*Événements*/

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ErreurConnexion.Visible = false;
        lblErreurConnexion.Text = "";
    }

    protected void btnConnexion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Authentifier(txtNomUtilisateur.Text, txtMotDePasse.Text))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtNomUtilisateur.Text, false);
        }
        else
        {
            ErreurConnexion.Visible = true;
            lblErreurConnexion.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            lblErreurConnexion.Text = "Erreur d'authentification : Le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe est incorrect.";
        }
    }

    /*Méthodes*/

    /// <summary>
    /// Méthode permettant l'authentification des utilisateurs à l'application
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="strNomUtilisateur">Nom de l'utilisateur saisi</param>
    /// <param name="strMotDePasse">Mot de passe saisi</param>
    /// <returns>Booléen vérifiant si l'authentification a été faite ou non</returns>

    private bool Authentifier(string strNomUtilisateur, string strMotDePasse)
    {
        bool bOk = false;
        // Cryptage du mot de passe
        strMotDePasse = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(strMotDePasse, "MD5");
        // Création d'une connexion SGBD
        SqlConnection oConnexion = new SqlConnection(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SaisieHeuresConnectionString"]));
        // Définition de la requête à exécuter
        SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Utilisateurs WHERE NomUtilisateur='" + strNomUtilisateur + "'", oConnexion);
        try
        {
            // Ouverture de la connexion et exécution de la requête
            oConnexion.Open();
            SqlDataReader drUtilisateur = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
            // Parcours de la liste des utilisateurs
            while (drUtilisateur.Read())
            {
                if (drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"].ToString() == strMotDePasse)
                {
                    bOk = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            bOk = false;
        }
        oConnexion.Close();
        return bOk;
    }
}
```

Here's the part on the second form for having the first and last name of the user thanks to the username and the password :

```
private static ConnexionSaisieHeures WebFormConnexionSaisieHeures = new ConnexionSaisieHeures();

private void PrenomNomUtilisateur()
        {
            SqlConnection oConnexion = new SqlConnection(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SaisieHeuresConnectionString"]));
            SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Utilisateurs WHERE NomUtilisateur='" + WebFormConnexionSaisieHeures.NomUtilisateur + "'", oConnexion);

            try
            {
                // Ouverture de la connexion et exécution de la requête
                oConnexion.Open();
                SqlDataReader drUtilisateur = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
                // Parcours de la liste des utilisateurs
                while (drUtilisateur.Read())
                {
                    if (drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"].ToString() == WebFormConnexionSaisieHeures.MotDePasse)
                    {
                        PrenomNom = drUtilisateur["PrenomNom"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex.Message);
            }
            oConnexion.Close();
        }
```

The aspx of my first webform :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ConnexionSaisieHeures.aspx.cs" Inherits="SaisieHeures.ConnexionSaisieHeures" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>WEATHER MEASURES : Connexion à l'application de saisie des heures</title>
    <link href="SaisieHeures.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        Saisie des heures - Connexion
    </header>

    <br />

    <article>
        <form id="FormConnexionSaisieHeures" runat="server">
            <table id="ErreurConnexion" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblErreurConnexion" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <table id="Connexion">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNomUtilisateur" runat="server" Text="Nom d'utilisateur :"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNomUtilisateur" runat="server" Style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMotDePasse" runat="server" Text="Mot de passe :"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMotDePasse" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnConnexion" runat="server" Text="Connexion" OnClick="btnConnexion_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

The aspx of my second webform :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SaisieHeures.aspx.cs" Inherits="SaisieHeures.SaisieHeures" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>WEATHER MEASURES : Application de saisie des heures</title>
    <link href="SaisieHeures.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        Saisie des heures - Application
    </header>

    <br />

    <article>
        <form id="FormSaisieHeures" runat="server">
            <table id="PrenomNomUtilisateur">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrenomNomUtilisateur" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <table id="SelectionMoisAnnee">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnMoisPrecedent" runat="server" Text="<" OnClick="btnMoisPrecedent_Click" />
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMoisAnnee" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnMoisSuivant" runat="server" Text=">" OnClick="btnMoisSuivant_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <table id="ErreurSaisie" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblErreurSaisie" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <table id="FicheSaisieHeures">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblChoixSemaine" runat="server" Text="Semaine : "></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSemaines" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSemaines_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblJours" runat="server" Text="Jours de la semaine"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNombreHeuresRealise" runat="server" Text="Nombre d'heures réalisées"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLundi" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeuresLundi" runat="server" Style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMardi" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeuresMardi" runat="server" Style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMercredi" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeuresMercredi" runat="server" Style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblJeudi" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeuresJeudi" runat="server" Style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblVendredi" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeuresVendredi" runat="server" Style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <table id="MessagesCalculTotalHeuresMois" runat="server">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMessageCalculTotalHeuresMois" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <table id="TotalHeuresMois">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblTotalHeuresMois" runat="server" Text="Nombre total d'heures réalisées dans le mois"></asp:Label>
                        <br />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCalculTotalHeuresMois" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <table id="Boutons">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnValider" runat="server" Text="Valider" OnClick="btnValider_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnAnnuler" runat="server" Text="Annuler" OnClick="btnAnnuler_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnGenererExcel" runat="server" Text="Générer Excel" OnClick="btnGenererExcel_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnDeconnexion" runat="server" Text="Déconnexion" OnClick="btnDeconnexion_Click" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

`txtNomUtilisateur.Text` is `null` ; it never recover the text entered by the user.

How can i solve it, please ?

(First Reedit with full code, i can had more informations i you need, i really want to solve it)

P.S. : @ElekGuidolin I reput the original code before your propositions to show you what i've originaly done.

Comment: When do you invoke this property?  Are you sure text is being entered?  Is something else overwriting the text?  There's nothing wrong with the code shown.

Comment: It is never null. Even if you assign `null` to the `Text` property `String.Empty` will be returned ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/TextBox.cs,92b4f85cd223169c,references))

Comment: I guess you have probably the `postback` issue based on *it never recover the text entered by the user*. Check this answer I hope it can solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/34545012/2946329

Comment: verify if its not getting set again during postbacks or in some other part of your code.

Comment: Are you using that code in web or windows forms?

Comment: @ElekGuidolin WebForm

Comment: Yes, thas'it @ChristopherLEBAS, check on my edited response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christopher.
Sorry about the confusion. But in fact I would like to improve the answer to a way better way to explain this.

When you are using Asp.Net Web Forms, you can get the value of your textbox with or without Request.Form, but only after a postback.
If you want to get the value from Request.Form, you will need to put inside the quotation marks the entire name of the field, which, if is an asp.Net control, it will be something like this: ctl00$FeaturedContent$txtMyTest.
But you can also get the value as the way you posted at first.

So, both ways work, but only after the postback, ok ?

If you are thinking in while typing the label will change together, you are talking about client script.
And that is a question to another post and another subject, right ?!

```
public string TestProperty
{
    get
    {
        //return txtMyTest.Text;
        return Request.Form["ctl00$FeaturedContent$txtMyTest"];
    }
    set
    {
        txtMyTest.Text = value;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        lblMyTest.Text = TestProperty;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
@ChristopherLEBAS, since as you are creating a new ConnexionSaisieHeures in your second Form, the values in the second will always be null, because you are creating them in that moment (private static ConnexionSaisieHeures WebFormConnexionSaisieHeures = new ConnexionSaisieHeures();), and not using the existent filled form.

As you want to have this information in other page, maybe the better way is to use either Session or Cookies, because you need to maintain the state between pages, so you can do something like this:

```
protected void btnConnexion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["NomUtilisateur"] = txtNomUtilisateur.Text;
    Session["MotDePasse"] = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(txtMotDePasse.Text, "MD5");

    if (Authentifier(txtNomUtilisateur.Text, txtMotDePasse.Text))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtNomUtilisateur.Text, false);
    }
    else
    {
        ErreurConnexion.Visible = true;
        lblErreurConnexion.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblErreurConnexion.Text = "Erreur d'authentification : Le nom d'utilisateur ou le mot de passe est incorrect.";
    }
}
```

And then, in the second form:

```
private void PrenomNomUtilisateur()
{
    string _NomUtilisateur = Session["NomUtilisateur"];
    string _MotDePasse = Session["MotDePasse"];
    SqlConnection oConnexion = new SqlConnection(Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SaisieHeuresConnectionString"]));
    SqlCommand oCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Utilisateurs WHERE NomUtilisateur='" + _NomUtilisateur + "'", oConnexion);

    try
    {
        // Ouverture de la connexion et exécution de la requête
        oConnexion.Open();
        SqlDataReader drUtilisateur = oCommand.ExecuteReader();
        // Parcours de la liste des utilisateurs
        while (drUtilisateur.Read())
        {
            if (drUtilisateur["MotDePasse"].ToString() == _MotDePasse)
            {
                PrenomNom = drUtilisateur["PrenomNom"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception : " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        oConnexion.Close();
    }
}
```

Note that I placed a Finally block, because if some error occurs, the connection will still be closed.

Comment: Unfortunately, HttpException : Request is not available in this context :(

Comment: You are using direct on the page ? I thought it was an User Control.
If it's in the same page, why do you need it to be a property ?

Comment: @ChristopherLEBAS More questions:
Does your button "Send" has a method to it's click event?
Where are you trying to get this value ?
The Button_Click? The Page_Load? Page_Init ?
All this depends on where and how you are trying to use it.

Comment: On my first webform, i click on a connection button that connect the user to my application. This last will recover the username and password (the good ones of course), compare it with the datas in my database, and show in a label in my second form the first and last name of the user that is connected.

Comment: I've found this. Can it solve my problem ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412152/asp-net-get-value-from-textbox-in-aspx-to-code-behind

Comment: I've also find this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678756/how-to-move-text-from-one-web-form-text-box-to-another-web-form-text-box

Comment: If you're using the Login control, the first link will work fine, and with the second one, you might consider that you are storing data in the server memory to get it after. Session always use server resources, and keep in the server memory until user logs off, so you have to be careful on when to use it. But I still don't understand why you can't use the txt.Text to retrieve the data you need.

Comment: For the code you give me above, i've got the same exception : Object Reference not set an instance of an object.

Comment: Oops, my bas, the exception is : Request is not available in this context  sorry

Comment: Can you edit your question and show me more code? Send the aspx and aspx.cs so I can understand better what are you trying to do...

Comment: Damn it. I've got red underlined under Session["NomUtilisateur"] and Session["MotDePasse"] ; the message is : Impossible to implicitly convert 'object' type in 'string' type. An explicit conversion exist v

Comment: (a cast-it is missing?)

Comment: It's good it's work i've found the mistake ; you've forgot a little thing at the end ; it's : Session["NomUtilisateur"].ToString(); Thank you very much, you were a great help to me. You are an excellent teacher ;)

Comment: Thank you Christopher. I'm glad I could help you.

Comment: Can you reedit your answer with the correction for the future persons that will read this post please ? Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: It's good i reedit myself your code with the correction ; i didn't see i have the possibility to do it. Thank you again for the help ;)